# Spinner arrow not visible in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning spinner in android and after adding border to the spinner the arrow on the right side is not visible. what modification should I make in my code so that the arrow will be visible?

this is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Gender:"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.052"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.87" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.066"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.175"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my spinner_border.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/black" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list></item>
</selector>
```

finally, this is my MainActivity.kt file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)

        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = this

        val categories: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        categories.add("Male")
        categories.add("Female")
        categories.add("Others")
        categories.add("Prefer Not To Say")

        val dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories)

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

        spinner.adapter = dataAdapter
    }


    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        val item = parent?.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh75i.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add Spinner in your xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"/>
```

In the drawable folder, spinner_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item><layer-list>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorWhite">
            </solid>

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/colorDarkGrey"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp" />
    </item>
  </layer-list></item>
</selector>
```

Hope above code will help you.